# Clone div dynamically with their textbox and buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to create following block dynamically when user click Add/Remove button.

```
<div id="divExtra" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" >
                <b>Extra</b>
                <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 3px;">
                    Color:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExtra_Color" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    Font Size:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExtra_FontSize" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    Family:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExtra_FontFamily" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    X:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExtra_X" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    Y:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtExtra_Y" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    Field :
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboExtraField" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkExtraBackside" Text="Is Back Side" />
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkExtraisImage" Text="Is Image" />
                </div>
</div>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

They can create this items many times. So at the end i am going to take this values and save them into database. So i can create my required block by the following code.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        myDiv.ID = "myDiv" + i;
        myDiv.InnerHtml = "<div id=\"divExtra" + i + "\" runat=\"server\" style=\"margin-bottom: 5px;\" visible=\"false\"><b>" + ddlTay.SelectedItem.Text + "</b><div style=\"border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 3px;\">Color:<input type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"txtExtra" + i + "_Color\"  Width=\"70px\"/>Font Size:<input type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"txtExtra1_FontSize\"  Width=\"70px\"/>Family:<input type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"txtExtra" + i + "_FontFamily\"  Width=\"70px\"/>X:<input type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"txtExtra" + i + "_X\"  Width=\"70px\"/>Y:<input type=\"text\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"txtExtra" + i + "_Y\"  Width=\"70px\"/>Is Back Side<input type=\"checkbox\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"chkExtra" + i + "Backside\" />Is Image<input type=\"checkbox\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"chkExtra" + i + "isImage\" /></div></div>";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myDiv);
    }
```

The problem is I want to save these values to my database and while page is loading, create the same structure base on saved value count.

Can someone help me with the code on this?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: this is too complicate to get some fast help, or some example code...

Comment: @Aristos ohh.. But is that clear what i am looking for basically?

Comment: You need Dynamic Controls. You cannot add `runat=server` to a string and expect a working Control. Webforms does not work that way.

Comment: Or create a `UserControl`.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for explanation. But i was trying to escape to writing multiple controls due to not destroy view, Anyhow I think i need to create controls for each items.